# When I create a supertype class and extend it, what happens to the constructor of the supertype?

Tags: php, oop, class, inheritance

Can I extend the constructor of the sueprtype? documentation doesnt say anything about extending functions.

I want to create a class which connects to a database when the subtypes are initialized but I don't want to write a connection code for each subtype. So I'd like to do it in the constructor of the supertype but I also want subtypes to have constructors.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/php-self-vs-this.) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136184/using-this-self-parent-for-code-readability)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can override the constructor just like any other method in a class:

```
<?php
class DbSuper {
    function __construct() {
        echo "db connection using super class<br/>";
    }
}

class DbSub extends DbSuper {
    function __construct() {
        echo "db connection using sub class<br/>";
    }
}

class DbSubNoConstr extends DbSuper {

}

class DbSubBothConstr extends DbSuper {
    function __construct() {
        echo "execute subclass code<br/>";
        parent::__construct();
    }

}

new DbSub(); //prints db connection using sub class
new DbSubNoConstr(); // prints db connection using super class
new DbSubBothConstr(); // prints execute subclass code db connection using super class
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Methods don't get "extended" per se; classes get extended.  The methods of those classes still exist, and can be invoked if they are scoped appropriately.

To more directly answer your question, you can call `parent::__construct()` to invoke the `__construct()` method of a superclass.  See [the PHP documentation on constructors and destructors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

From php.net

> Note: Parent constructors are not called implicitly if the child class
>   defines a constructor. In order to run a parent constructor, a call to
>   parent::__construct() within the child constructor is required.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

So what you do is connect to the database in the superclass constructor. Then create your subclass constructor and call `parent::__construct()`

But, it would probably be better to explicitly connect. In the base class call `$this->connect()`, which would be defined in the parent class.

Answer (score 1):

Just as you can use `parent::methodName()` to call the parents version of a function, so you can call `self::methodName()` to call the current classes implementation of a method.

This links may help u

#### http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#102275